# SCNNode not moving due to animation

Tags: swift, scenekit, game-development

I created SCNNode object and added simple CABasicAnimation that just spins my object. I used to set velocity to the physics body of my node, but it’s not moving while animation is playing. However other animations which were created in blender are working.
Example:

```
self.node = SCNNode()
let obj = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/player.scn")!
self.node = (obj.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Body", recursively: true))!

let spin = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "rotation")
spin.fromValue = NSValue(scnVector4: SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, w: 0))
spin.toValue = NSValue(scnVector4: SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, w: Float(CGFloat(2 * Double.pi))))
spin.duration = 1
spin.repeatCount = .infinity
        self.node.addAnimation(SCNAnimation(caAnimation: spin), forKey: "spin")

scene.rootNode.addChildNode(self.node)

self.player.node.physicsBody?.velocity.x = 2.0  // not working together with animation
```